# How do I get files found by command-line 'find' ordered by modification date in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, find

Using the Mac OS X Terminal, how do I write a `find` command that orders results by modification date (most recent first)?

There are similar questions already, but they refer to GNU `find` and POSIX, but I do not know whether Mac OS X is GNU or POSIX or something else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OS X is fully [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliant.

Something like that should do:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tl
```

Some notes:

- The `-t` option in `ls` will sort by `mtime`.
- `xargs` is used to pass the filenames as an argument to `ls`. Note that you have to use `-print0` in `find` and `-0` in `xargs` if you have files with spaces in their names. Also, the maximum amount of arguments is [limited by the `ARG_MAX` variable](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/). To find out how many these are, enter `getconf ARG_MAX`.
- You can supply `-r` to reverse the sort order (→ oldest files first)
- The other `find` and `ls` options are – as usual – outlined in the manuals (`man find` or `man ls`).

Comment: `ls -ltr` to reverse the order.

Comment: Xe'll only get them sorted within groups of (slightly less than) `ARG_MAX` filename characters that way, of course.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the addition @JdeBP and Daniel. `getconf ARG_MAX` will show that number.

Comment: ah my problem now is that I am using this command in a applescript, and was using the result to read the contents of that file.  But now the result contains date information, not just the filename:

 do shell script "find /Users/akw/Library/Preferences/ByHost/ -name 'com.apple.windowserver*' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tl | head -1"
  returns this --> "-rw-------@ 1 akw  staff  5512 Jun 19 07:52 /Users/akw/Library/Preferences/ByHost//com.apple.windowserver.1FC3A841-2C0C-5F48-B746-1DEE064F6D12.plist"

Comment: @zadam then use `ls -t` instead of `ls -tl`. The `-l` gives you a long listing including the dates. I didn't know what you were trying to do exactly, so sorry for that - I assumed you would like to see the `mtime` as well.