# How to get find to search for files in alphabetically order?

Tags: unix, find

I am wondering if there is a way to run the `find` command and make it go through the directories (recursively) in alphabetical order (or in reverse)? I have a bunch of directories with names representing some order and often I need to find the earliest (or the last) based on the directory name.

There are questions and answers on how sorting the results returned by `find` (see below). However, I am interested to know if there is a way to make `find` to run the search alphabetically because it would be much more efficient than going through the whole thing and then sort.

Ideally, I can specify the command to stop after `n` hits are found, but that's secondary because I can also stop the command manually.

[How do I get files found by command-line 'find' ordered by modification date in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/298832/how-do-i-get-files-found-by-command-line-find-ordered-by-modification-date-in)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34325/sorting-the-output-of-find

Answer (score 1):

`find`'s directory listing order is given by the order of the entries stored in the filesystem.

You could consider writing a bash script that goes into each directory and lists the needed files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

`find -type d -maxdepth 1 | sort -h | xargs find`

`find -type d -maxdepth 1` lists directories, without recursing. We pipe the output into `sort -h`, to sort the results in a human-centric way. The sorted list of directories gets sent to `xargs` which uses them as command-line arguments for the final `find`, the one that does the majority of the work.

I know you wanted to avoid sort, but AFAIK, find is going to go through the file system by the filesystem's order.

Hope this helps.