# Find the most recent file of a type in terminal and then open it (mac os)

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, find, open

I found part of this question in 2 other posted questions, but I cant seem to get the last step working which is just "opening" the file:

[How do I get files found by command-line 'find' ordered by modification date in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/298832/how-do-i-get-files-found-by-command-line-find-ordered-by-modification-date-in)

[macOS Terminal find most recent file in directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1277737/macos-terminal-find-most-recent-file-in-directory)

The end goal is to find the most recent file open by a specific application (in this case, a ".vesp64" file) and then open it automatically on restart.

I figure the "automatically on restart" thing can be sorted as making the script a login item unless there is a better way to do it.

I've tried running this

`find . -type f -name "*.vesp64" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tl dir | head -n 1`

which seems to work to find the file I need, but then how do I open the file it found?

edit : there is no way to recall the last state it was in automatically like other apps, so I need to find a way to do it in terminal. this is the program https://www.vsl.co.at/en/Vienna_Software_Package/Vienna_Ensemble_Pro

Comment: Will it not just reopen in the same state it was quit, or does it not have a recents menu option?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start the application with

```
ViennaEnsemblePro file.vesp64
```

I'm not on a mac, and I have not used that application, so you might want to check if that statement is correct. Apparently, on Windows that seems to work like that.

Then, use `xargs`, just like you did for the `ls`. Personnally, I would not use `ls` for this; an alternative would be:

```
find . -printf "%T@ #-# %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's/.*#-# //' | tail -1 | xargs ViennaEnsemblePro
```